# Consequences of setting QueueExpiration in MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

If I set `QueueExpiration` in MassTransit during configuration to 5 hours, does that mean that the queue will be deleted if no activity has happened in the queue for 5 hours, or will it delete itself even if there is activity, after 5 hours?

**Edit:** I am using RabbitMQ transport, and I am setting it inside the IOC configuration step.

Comment: Which transport, and how would you set it? I'd suggest updating the _question_.

Comment: @chrispatterson I clarified a bit now - was that what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue will be deleted if there is no activity for five hours. A connected bus with a receive endpoint on the queue is considered "activity" even if there are no messages received.